# Ascenders tops showing in fixed height div (overflow hidden)

Tags: html, css

I have a div exactly four line-heights high.

The tops of ascenders of the (hidden) fifth line are showing.

How can I prevent this?

*I am reluctant to just make the div a bit shorter, as this could chop the bottom of the descenders off in different browser/platform.*

**Chrome 53.0 on Android:**

[image: Chrome 53.0 on Android]

**Firefox 49.0 on Lubuntu:**

[image: Firefox 49.0 on Lubuntu]

**Source code:**

```css
div
{
 font-size: 22px;

 line-height: 1.2em;
 height: 5em;   /* exactly (4 * line-height) */
 overflow: hidden;

 width: 200px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`height` has to be 4.8em (i.e. 1.2 * 4)

```css
div
{
 font-size: 22px;

 line-height: 1.2em;
 height: 4.8em;   /* exactly (4 * line-height) */
 overflow: hidden;

 width: 200px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - now I feel stupid! I still actually get the same artifact on chrome but I reckon 4.79 might cure it.

Comment: It also depends on the font: Some characters in some fonts really have ascenders that go above line-height.

Comment: Despite fixing this obvious mistake, I realised there is actually a bug causing this. The workaround I found is to use integer pixel values for font-size and line-height.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to adjust height as much as possible depending on your line height.

```css
div
{
 font-size: 22px;

 line-height: 1.2em;
 height: 4.85em;   /* exactly (4 * line-height) */
 overflow: hidden;

 width: 200px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```